# Creating Desktop applications that run on web browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

In the last year I got to know that many developers started developing desktop applications that run on the web browser.

I am also trying to get into it and I'm trying to understand how I should start with such kind of development.

I first thought I should create a regular client-server application, i.e. with Apache Tomcat or with PHP, and for each launch of an application, to launch a new server on localhost and to open a browser that will load the application.

I've lately got to know that there are packages that do the server-client work for you, such as node-webkit.

I don't know where to start and I'm very confused...

When developers say that they develop desktop applications in Javascript or such that run on web browser - do they probably mean that the use node-webkit? Or does they do the complex structure I described above (JSP/PHP server on localhost) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the wrong place for this question. Stackoverflow is about programming issues and debugging code; not library recommendations.

Comment: If I don't know how to start working - I won't be able to ask questions about it :) It's a "how to start" question. I didn't ask for recommendation on a language

Comment: @NickDugger I think it is quite a beginner question, but I don't think stackoverflow is the the wrong place for it. Many threads are for things far from debugging code, including framework suggestions and system architecture decisions.

Comment: I guess the asker want to know how to build web app that can do the function & mimic the desktop app counterpart (eg: MS Office Online, Visual Studio Online that can build projects on the serverside, etc)..

Comment: This is similar to what I meant, but not exactly. AFAIK, Office Online and similar apps have server side, existing on the provider's servers, while I meant to an application in which the server is on `localhost`, so it has access e.g. to files on your machine, like any other desktop application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many development models with web technologies exist, but they have different purposes and it all depends on what you want to do.

You seem to be mixing 3 models

**Classic websites**

A server (with PHP, Java or whatever) generates HTML.

A user uses a browser to access it.

When the user clicks somewhere, the server is called again and generates another HTML file.

**Single Page Applications**

This model is often used when writing websites that need a lot of interactivity. For example Gmail, or Google docs are SPAs (more or less).

SPAs are websites (you can access them at an URL) where all templating is done client side, and the webserver only exposes a HTTP API.

Most of the times, people use frameworks to make those like:

- AngularJS
- React
- Backbone

**Desktop apps with web technologies**

That's just coding an application that you can install on a computer or phone with web technologies (javascript, css, html).

There is no server.

Tools that enable programmers to do this are

- Node webkit (for desktops)
- Cordova (for phones)
- Many others

Most of the time, programmers also use SPA tools in conjonction with those to help them during development

Comment: So you actually say that there is a total difference between development of a client application that should contact with a central server (like Gmail), and a desktop application that runs locally and has permissions like a regular local application in C or other desktop language. You say that my idea of launching a PHP server for each instance of the local desktop application is not a good idea and is even a strange one :)     right?

Comment: If you want to make a desktop application, users will install it like any other application. This application can be made in C, Python, or javascript and HTML (if you use node webkit). Your desktop app can communicate with APIs on the web, if you need it to, but that's unrelated with which tech you choose for development. A python, or C local application can call APIs as well

Comment: PHP is a different matter, it's a language that's done to work only on webservers (more or less, there is a cli, but i would not recommend it), so you can't use it locally on your user's computer, because you don't want to install an Apache/MySQL stack there!

Answer (score 4):

The selection of technologies for building an application depends on the use of your application and the platform you want it to run on.

Web applications in contrast to Desktop applications are hosted and served by servers (like Tomcat) which are then requested and present to you by your browser.

Desktop applications are running on your local machine and they are independent from your browser. However node webkit, allows you to design applications using HTML and making them dynamic using node. The end result is a standalone application that runs as a browser emulation that is able to render and run software based on HTML and javascript. (In this case nodejs serves the application locally and the standalone web-app is the client).

Long story short node-webkit emulates the client-server model that is used for classic web apps, to build desktop applications.

It is an unorthodox way for doing things IMHO, but it might be a good start for getting into application development.

Comment: I have a few years of experience in development in Java, Python, C and even with web development with JSP and HTML4. I just didn't understand how this desktop development with Javascript works. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Each technology stack has its own tools for achieving what you want to do. In this case you should rather look for the platform that you intend to build something on, rather than looking for what can be used based on what you already know eg. .NET for Windows aps, Cocoa for OS X, LAMP, Tomcat, JSP for client-server apps etc.
There are always alternatives like Java Swing, but this has always to do with what you want to do and how.
I'm not a node-webkit expert but some research might help you. Check http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

https://electronjs.org/

Build cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. With Electron, creating a desktop application for your company or idea is easy. Initially developed for GitHub's Atom editor, Electron has since been used to create applications by companies like Microsoft, Facebook, Slack, and Docker.